# Provider hosted sharepoint app, create a SharePoint calendar

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I creating a provider hosted app that should create a calendarlist in SharePoint. I want it to    be a group calendar later on but first I just need to do step 1: Create a calendar.

I cant find any provider hosted guides on how to create a SharePoint-calendar programmatically. I cant find a `ListTemplateStyle` for calendar so I tried the event-template, I dont know if its goint to work since there's an error showing up when I try to run this code below:

```
 Uri hostWeb = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);

        using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity))
        {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            ListCreationInformation listCreator = new ListCreationInformation();
            listCreator.Title = "CompanyCalendar";
            listCreator.Description = "Workcalendar";
            listCreator.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.Events; //106 = events
            //clientContext.Load(web);
            web.Lists.Add(listCreator);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        }
```

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.

```
Line 27:                 //clientContext.Load(web);
Line 28:                 web.Lists.Add(listCreator);
Line 29:                 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
Line 30: 
Line 31:             }
```

It seems like im unauthorized to create a list here for some reason. I have web permission set to full control and my cert looks like this:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ClientId" value="ebcb24ca-afbb-4822-8887-f91504f3d25f" />
<add key="ClientSigningCertificatePath" value="C:\Certs\HighTrustSampleCert.pfx" />
<add key="ClientSigningCertificatePassword" value="1234" />
<add key="IssuerId" value="11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111" />
</appSettings>
```

Any idéas?

my second question is: What do I have to learn to make the calendar a group calendar? Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/509e099f-7f0d-4c52-9ad9-cf3d8b270d34/how-to-customize-input-form-for-sharepoint-2010-calendar?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious may help. Above URL contain similar discussion

Comment: I guess I cant create a Calendar programmatically so I guess I have to create a generic list first and then create a CalendarView somehow. But my problem here is that I dont get permission to create a simple list on my developer site. I dont know what to do :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own.

I apperently used a SharePoint developer-site to debugg on (in my case "https://mysite@company.onmicrosoft.com"). Since I work on a virtual machine I should use that local server-site instead (in my case `"http://SERVER1`").

When I login to my virtual machine I login with my windows username and password (in my case the username was "Developer") and to be able to use that login with the codesnippet `"Request.LogonUserIdentity"` my debug site had to be the virtual server (in my case `"http://SERVER1`").

After I changed to SERVER1 it worked and `ListTemplateType.Events` **wich is the template for a calendar** gets created and the problem is solved.

**Question 1:** How to create a sharepointcalendar.
*Answear: `(int)ListTemplateType.Events;`*

**Question 2:** `System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.` 
*Answear: Check your debugsite. Make sure that `"Request.LogonUserIdentity"` or(the user you logged in to windows with) has promission to your site that you debug towards*

**Question 3:** How to set the "group calendar option" to `"true"` programmatically on a privider hosted app. 
*Answear: **Not solved** :(*